How to remove ntfs permission of a specific user on a directory with powershell?
This script tries to do the following

create SHARE, disable inheritance and convert inherited rules to explicits rules.
remove any rights from BUILTIN\Utilisateurs on this directory

Unfortunately, at the end, the rights remains the same, and Utilisateurs is still in the rules !
What am I doing wrong ?
$sharePath = "C:\SHARE"

New-Item -Path $sharePath -ItemType Directory
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $sharePath
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $true)
Set-Acl -Path $sharePath -AclObject $acl

Write-Host "Before :"
$acl.Access | Format-List *

$groupToRemove = "BUILTIN\Utilisateurs"
foreach ($accessRule in $acl.Access) {
    if ($accessRule.IdentityReference -eq $groupToRemove) {
        # Delete the rule. It seems to work because it returns true in powershell
        $acl.RemoveAccessRule($accessRule)
    }
}

Set-Acl -Path $sharePath -AclObject $acl

Write-Host "After :"
$acl.Access | Format-List *


The code that works is enumerating through the objects while code that doesn't work is not enumerating through the objects.

Solved, you need to get the acl again after disabling inheritance
$sharePath = "C:\SHARE"

New-Item -Path $sharePath -ItemType Directory
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $sharePath
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $true)
Set-Acl -Path $sharePath -AclObject $acl

# NEED TO GET THE ACL AGAIN
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $sharePath

Write-Host "Before :"
$acl.Access | Format-List *

$groupToRemove = "BUILTIN\Utilisateurs"
foreach ($accessRule in $acl.Access) {
    if ($accessRule.IdentityReference -eq $groupToRemove) {
        # Delete the rule. It seems to work because it returns true in powershell
        $acl.RemoveAccessRule($accessRule)
    }
}

Set-Acl -Path $sharePath -AclObject $acl

Write-Host "After :"
$acl.Access | Format-List *

